# How does the default Microsoft CNG Key Storage Provider protect keys?

Tags: mscapi

I presume the keys are not stored on disk in plain-text, but are at least obfuscated somehow.  The question is "how?"  I am particularly interested in non-machine keys which do not have an associated password.

My google-fu has been distressingly weak here.